# Determining how many processes run using fork

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

I have this snippet code, and I would like to determine how many processes run_morecompute. I am learning OS and I am struggling with the concept of forking.

Thank you

```
void run_morecompute(int i){
   printf("hello world");
}
void run_compute(int i) {
    int cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == 0)
    run_morecompute(i);
}

int main (){
   int pid;
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      pid = fork();
      if (pid == 0){
        printf("\n%d",i);
        run_compute(i);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Put the `\n` at the end of the printf format string, not the beginning. Stdout is line-buffered, so the line won't be printed until you print a newline.

Comment: Why doesn't `run_morecompute()` use the `i` parameter?

Comment: Can't you just count the number of times `hello world` is printed? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
printf("hello world");
```

to

```
printf("hello world from %d", getpid());
```

It will add the process ID to the output.  It may help you understand how many processes get created.

I'd suggest changing the loop in main to just call run_morecompute() until you get a handle on what is happening.  The additional fork() in run_compute() makes things more complicated.

The top level process forks 4 child processes that call run_compute().  Those 4 children then become parents and fork 3 more children each. Then those 12 children fork 2 more processes each... etc.

Hope that helps.